# Dapper return multiple results with one query

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, dapper

I want to return two result with one query. For instance the queried table and furthermore I want to return the size of the whole table.

I can not do it in c# because I only want to query for instance the first 100 results but it should be possible for the customer to query the next 100 results. But beforehand I want to show the customer if there are further results.

For instance I have a table with 150 results. In the first call I get only the first 100 results. But I also want to get the information that there are still 50 results left without calling a second query. Is this possible with dapper?

Comment: Get the total number of records, the first 100 records and total - 100 using a single query?

Answer (score 2):

You can try QueryMultiple:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Integrated Security=true; Initial Catalog=foo"))
{
    using (var data = conn.QueryMultiple("select count(*) as TotalCount from data; select top 2 * from data", null))
    {
        var totalRecords = data.Read<int>().Single();
        var records = data.Read<dynamic>();
        var remaining = totalRecords - records.Count();
    }
}
```

Comment: This may fulfill requirement of OP but this is not exactly what he is asking for. This will still execute two queries. It will batch them. I agree with @mm8.

Comment: It's two sql queries, but a single trip to the DB.

Answer (score 2):

If you really just want to know IF there are more results and *not* how many, you could limit your results to 101.  Then toss out the 101st row which is just an indicator that there is more than 100 rows.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this possible with dapper?

Dapper is just an an object-relational mapper, i.e. maps from an object-oriented domain model to a relational database. You still need to ask the database (using a query) how many records there are in total. Dapper won't magically figure this out for you.

So you need to modify the query that you send to the database (using Dapper) to select not only the first 100 rows from a table but also an additional column that contains a number that specifies the total number of records in the table. Only the database knows this number so you will have to ask it for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also query the whole table but only show the first 100 rows, and you already know if there's more data to show when the user ask for the next set of data